# After URL redirection, url not displaying new address when clicking on links

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, joomla, content-management-system, url-rewriting

I've got this website, http://www.manndirectory.com, it's a Joomla CMS with the SOBI2 business index installed. I've set it up so that their can be different entries based on their building location. SEF is turned on for both Joomla and SOBI2.

I've set up 301 redirects so that if you type in www(dot)manndirectory(dot)com/1407 or www(dot)manndirectory(dot)com/1500, it will take you to a homepage with info for that building.

That works fine but clicking on any link will not change the URL in the address bar.

Here is that code in the htaccess file
Redirect 301 /fashion_directory/1407 http://www(dot)manndirectory(dot)com/index.php?building=1407
Redirect 301 /fashion_directory/1500 http://www(dot)manndirectory(dot)com/index.php?building=1500

I'd rather use URL rewriting than redirection. It's just a temporary solution implemented.

I'd like this URL:
http://www(dot)manndirectory(dot)com/index.php?building=1407

to display as:
http://www(dot)manndirectory(dot)com/1407

And I'd like all subpages to append after the 1407 (ex http://www(dot)manndirectory(dot)com/1407/a/ or http://www(dot)manndirectory(dot)com/1407/activewear/vestiti-fini.html

Can anyone shed some light on this. I realize it is an indepth question to a very intensive problem. But I'm at a bit of a loss.

BELOW IS THE HTACCESS FILE I AM USING:

```
##
# @version $Id: htaccess.txt 14401 2010-01-26 14:10:00Z louis $
# @package Joomla
# @copyright Copyright (C) 2005 - 2010 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# Joomla! is Free Software
##


#####################################################
#  READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
#
#####################################################

##  Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymLinks

#
#  mod_rewrite in use

RewriteEngine On
# RewriteRule ^/1407$ /tmp

########## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits
## If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
## This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
## Deny access to extension xml files (uncomment out to activate)
#<Files ~ "\.xml$">
#Order allow,deny
#Deny from all
#Satisfy all
#</Files>
## End of deny access to extension xml files
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode crap to send via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Send all blocked request to homepage with 403 Forbidden error!
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [F,L]
#
########## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits

#  Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
#  is not directly related to physical file paths.
#  Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root)

# RewriteBase /


########## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/|\.php|\.html|\.htm|\.feed|\.pdf|\.raw|/[^.]*)$  [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) index.php
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
#
########## End - Joomla! core SEF Section

Redirect 301 /fashion_directory/1407 http://www.manndirectory.com/index.php?building=1407

#RewriteRule index/building/(.*)/ index.php?building=$1
#RewriteRule index/building/(.*) index.php?building=$1
```

Comment: I would suggest stripping out commented code from above file and keep only relevant lines above so you can have better chances of getting answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you want new URLs you must link to those new URLs from the pages of your site.

URLs are defined in the links that the user clicks on.

Mod_rewrite cannot change the links on the pages of a site. Instead it reacts to a URL request coming from the browser after the link is clicked.

Your .htaccess file is an old version. There were many changes recently made. These changes appeared in the Joomal 1.5.23 and 1.6.2 versions of the file.